# How do you get real number to dollar values

Tags: java, computer-science

I am having trouble writing the code for a program that reads a number then prints out that amount in $ value using the least amount of bills.This is all i could come up with.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Assignment3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter amount) ");
     double amount = input.nextDouble();
     int amountInt = (int) (amount * 100);

    if(amount >= 100)
    {
            amount = amount % 100;
        }
    if(amount >= 50)
        {
            amount = amount % 50;
        }
    if(amount >= 20)
        amount= amount % 50;
        }
    if(amount >= 10) 
        amount= amount %10; 
        }
    if(amount >= 5) 
        amount= amount %5; 
        }
    if(amount >= 1) 
        amount = amount %1;
        }
    if(amount >= .25)
        amount =amount %.25;
        }
    if(amount >= .10)
        amount = amount %.10;
        }
    if(amount >= .05)
        amount = amount % .05;
        }
    if(amount >= .01) 
        amount = amount % .01;
        }
```

Comment: You'll want to look into utilizing some modular arithmetic.

Comment: How would you describe what your program does to a 5 year old? Write that down, then implement it step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done this way:

```
int tmp;
if(amount >= 100)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/100
        print tmp + "$100 bills"
        amount = amount % 100
    }
if(amount >= 50)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/50
        print tmp + "$50 bills"
        amount = amount % 50
    }
```

I can see on your naming this is an assignment, so you'll have to fix the syntax yourself. You also need to continue this for the lower bills.

Here is an explanation though.
If the amount is equal or over a hundred we divide it by a hundred and cast it to an int. This will automatically result in how many times a hundred goes up into our number. So for 455, (int) 455/100 will be 4. We print that, and we update our amount. amount % 100, subtracts 100 from amount, as many times as possible (in this case, 4 times).

We continue doing this, printing dollar bills and updating our amount.

edit:
clarification of what does what, and how it works per request:

First we check if the amount is above 100, as 100 is the largest dollar bill. If it is we do:
`tmp = (int) amount/100`
This is how many times we can subtract 100 from the amount, and we save this value. If the `amount` is 640, `tmp` will now be 6.

We then print the out the dollar bills, first printing the amount (`tmp`) and then printing the type of dollar bill.

Afterwards we update `amount`.
`amount % 100` subtracts 100 from `amount` as many times as possible.
If we continue with the example of 640, it will do:
`640-100=540`
`540-100=440`
`440-100=340`
`340-100=240`
`240-100=140`
`140-100= 40`
As such, `amount` will be left with just 40.

We continue this process with the remaining amount for all remaining dollar bill sizes.

Comment: I updated the code above but I am confused still on how to calculate the amount of change, and pluralizing the denominations since hundred can be used more than once..etc

Comment: @patm, i added some more explanation, hopefully it is clear how it works.

Comment: I understand the arithmatic but isn't it supposed to be a stored as a double value not an int? Also, what is tmp?